# Custom button behaves differently in different sandboxes

Tags: custom-button, sandbox, popup-window

I am fairly new to salesforce and have never used a sandbox before. Currently, I am working with two sandboxes provided by a client. In one sandbox a custom button I added by using URL hack is working perfectly but in another sandbox, it does not even open the popup. There are also some dissimilarities between those two, for example, if I don't enter a required field value in one sandbox the error message shows at the top of the popup in other sandboxes it shows at bottom of the popup using a small note like message. Can someone explain why these two are behaving differently?

Comment: What kind of button it is? Where are you using them? Can you add screenshot?

Comment: @sanketkumar it is a new record creation button for that object which also prepopulates some of the lookup fields like related account. I already fixed the button by removing the backgroundContext parameter from the link, but why it is working now I do not know. Also if I remove backgroundContext from the other sandbox it does not work anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the definition of the buttons and actions or layouts? Looks like your sandboxes have different configuration as they were either not refreshed at the same time, or they where refreshed using different orgs as templates. But as you say, the sandboxes do not seem to have the same metadata.

You have three options:

- refresh the sandboxes using the same org as template (either a Dev SB or production),
- spin up two new sandboxes.
  The above may not be possible due to integrations or other dependencies.
- deploy differing metadata from production to your sandboxes.
  This way you have whatever config production has. However, chances are big that you will run into other dissimilarities.

Comment: I will look into it. Also, I noticed something else, if any validation rule fails in the new popup, in the older sandbox the error message is shown at the top of the popup and it does not show all the fields that need attention just the first one, but in the newer sandbox, it shows error popup at the bottom in a message dialogue box and it shows all the fields that need attention. Is it something due to internal changes in salesforce?

Comment: Most likely. Take a look a the validation rule definition (Setup -> Object Manager -> [Your Object] -> Validation Rules. This is also (to me) an indication that the sandboxes where refreshed at different times.